# Customers think they get charged twice (PayPal) while one of the authorizations drops off. PayPal says this is a problem with Magento

Tags: paypal, paypal-payments-pro

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
Amasty extensions
PayPal Payments Pro
```

I use PayPal Payments Pro on my Magento 2.4.2-p1 site. My customers get upset because there are 2 identical authorizations for the purchase amount. One of these drops off eventually but customers call and are concerned.

I have raised a ticket with PayPal and *they have responded with the following*:

"I found some more information here:

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360051109051-MDVA-31282-Magento-patch-double-authorization-on-Paypal-PayFlow-Pro

Looks like you can install a patch update from Magento to help with this issue."

The issues with this link are:

1. It is for Paypal PayFlow Pro -- we do not use Paypal PayFlow Pro; **we use PayPal Payments Pro**.
2. The suggested fix says: "compatible with Magento Commerce and Magento Commerce Cloud 2.3.2 - 2.3.3 and 2.3.5 - 2.3.6."; **I have Magento 2.4.2-p1.**

**How to fix this?**

---

UPDATED on December 9th, 2021:

This happens on 2 websites/stores on the same Magento 2.4.2-p1 install.

[image]

This is what one transaction on my 2nd website/store looks like. All transactions seem like this. As you see we have "captured" but it seems the preauthorization still stands.

[image]

The first website/store is the same. You can clearly see it creates a new charge instead of capturing the pre-authorization. **Website/store 1 uses a different PayPal account than website/store 2 so this is not likely going to be a PayPal issue?**

*We capture the payments on Magento, NOT through PayPal.*

---

UPDATED on December 10th, 2021:

Just to clarify - **our customers do not get charged twice!** *They only get charged once* but **Magento creates 2 authorizations which the customers see and get upset about.** One of the authorizations eventually drops off (in about 5 days) but it makes customers angry and they call us about it.

I also had a very long conversation with PayPal and they claim this happens to all Magento 2 customers and *

> "that's just how Magento 2 does it = makes 2 authorizations for each
> and every purchase!"

**Surely, that's not right, is it?**

---

Updated on December 16th, 2021:

**Magento creates 2 authorizations for each and every order on 2 different websites/stores on the same Magento 2.4.2-p1 install.**

PayPal looked into this and responded with the following:

*"Our apologies for the frustration.
PayPal cannot make two authorizations for a single order. For each order initiated from the buyer, PayPal will generate a unique token that can be only used once. We would suggest checking with your developer for this as the requests must come from your end. If there is anything needed from our end then please let us know."*

**One of the authorizations eventually drops off (in about 5 days) but it makes customers angry and they call us about it.**

---

I just found the following article:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Payments-PayPal/Magento-2-amp-Paypal-Pro-Double-Authorization-Fees/td-p/87356

*Is this something that can help us?*

---

UPDATED on December 20th, 2021:

*Here is what I think is happening.* I am not actually the person within our Organization who processes payments. The people who do, open the order up and click on INVOICE, then SUBMIT INVOICE in order to 'capture' the payment. **I believe this is NOT the correct process?** Is this option there for off-line payments such as checks etc.? ***It should probably not be used with PayPal Payments Pro?***

**What are the correct steps/workflow (step by step) on how to process payments/orders when we have PayPal for payment processor and are set up with the (PayPal) Payments Pro payment option in the Admin panel?**

Comment: A try would be applying that quality patch, see the code changes under some version control tool & then try to extrapolate them to the module you are using

Comment: The first authorization of 0$ is just to make sure that the card is valid before sending  the real authorization request. So I guess that if you want to remove it you will have to check into paypal code to remove the card validation before doing the real authorization. I do not suggest doing it and I would rather add something in the order confirmation email to explain this double authorization than to start making change to the paypal plugin

Comment: @Carlo Ricci I now believe this could be a user Error? I am not actually the person who processes payments. The people who do open the order up and click on INVOICE, then SUBMIT INVOICE in order to 'capture' the payment. I believe this is NOT the correct process? Is this option there for off-line payments such as checks etc.? It should probably not be used with PayPal Payments Pro? What are the correct steps/workflow (step-by-step) on how to process payments/orders when we have PayPal for payment processor and are set up with the (PayPal) Payments Pro payment option in the Admin panel? Thanks.

Comment: Opening the order and clicking on invoice then submit invoice is the right thing to do . There should be a backend process that will try to capture the payment inside paypal (if capture online is checked) to check if the invoice can be created. If the payment cannot be processed the invoicing in magento should fail. The process is quite similar for all payment plaform offline or online. For offline method the difference is there is no real verification to see if the payment is really captured or no. For example for check money order, you might want to invoice only when you receive the check.

Answer (score -2):

Why has my credit or debit card been charged twice?

When there are multiple charges for the same transaction on your credit or debit card, it may be because you inadvertently clicked Send Money more than once.

Comment: With all the respect, this is not correct. Customers do not get charged twice! They only get charged once but Magento creates 2 authorizations which the customers see and get upset about. One of the authorizations eventually drops off (in about 5 days) but it makes customers angry and they call us about it.